# Inserting a floating point number in a table using libpq

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

I am inserting a floating point number in a table using `libpq`. I am getting this error `INSERT failed: ERROR:  insufficient data left in message`.

Here is the corresponding snippet from my code base:

```
printf ("Enter write parameter_value");
scanf("%f", &parameter_value);

char *stm = "INSERT INTO write_reg_set (parameter_value) VALUES ($1::double precision)";

int nparam = 1;

//set the values to use
const char *values[1] = {(char *)&parameter_value};

//calculate the lengths of each of the values
int lengths[1] = {sizeof(parameter_value)};

//state which parameters are binary
int binary[1] = {1};

PGresult *res = PQexecParams(conn,
                     stm,
                     nparam,  //number of parameters
                     NULL,    //ignore the Oid field
                     values,  //values to substitute $1 and $2 and so on
                     lengths, //the lengths, in bytes, of each of the parameter values
                     binary,  //whether the values are binary or not
                     0);      //we want the result in text format

if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "INSERT failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
    exit_nicely(conn,res);
}
PQclear(res);
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two errors in your code:

- You are trying to send binary data, but you don't tell `PQexecParams` which type it is.

  That cannot work. Lacking type information, PostgreSQL will use the type `unknown` and treat it as string. That means that your binary representation will be fed to the `float8in` function that converts strings to double precision values, which will fail horribly. This is probably what you are observing.

  You will have to use a fourth parameter with an `Oid[]` that contains 701 (or `FLOAT8OID` if you'd rather use PostgreSQL's `#define`, but you'd have to `#include <postgres.h>` and `<catalog/pg_type.h>` for that).
- You mistakenly assume that PostgreSQL's binary representation of the `double precision` type is the binary format for `double` in use on your client machine.

  This might accidentally work if your program is running on a [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) machine, since virtually every architecture these days uses [IEEE floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

  If you read the source code, you'll find that PostgreSQL's over-the-wire binary format ist defined in `pq_sendfloat8` in `src/backend/libpq/pqformat.c`, which calls `pq_sendint64`, which converts the 8-byte value to network byte order (which is the same as big-endian representation).

So you'd have to define a conversion function similar to this:

```
static void to_nbo(double in, double *out) {
    uint64_t *i = (uint64_t *)&in;
    uint32_t *r = (uint32_t *)out;

    /* convert input to network byte order */
    r[0] = htonl((uint32_t)((*i) >> 32));
    r[1] = htonl((uint32_t)*i);
}
```

Then your code could look like this:

```
Oid types[1];
double converted;

...

types[0] = FLOAT8OID;
to_nbo(value, &converted);
values[0] = (char *)&converted;
```

But frankly, it would be much easier to use the text representation. That will make your code independent of PostgreSQL internals and probably is not so much slower.

It doesn't look like it, but if the `double precision` values are pulled from a PostgreSQL table somewhere else, you could set [`extra_float_digits`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-EXTRA-FLOAT-DIGITS)`= 3` so that you are guaranteed not to lose any precision when the values are converted to their string representation..

Comment: 1st point: testlibpq2.c says ergarding OID "let the backend deduce param type" for both binary and text examples. Thatswhy I omitted it. your 2nd point is valid.

Comment: How do you think is the backend supposed to deduce that 4 bytes you pass it are a double? [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQEXECPARAMS)says: *If paramTypes is NULL, or any particular element in the array is zero, the server infers a data type for the parameter symbol in the same way it would do for an **untyped literal string**.* (emphasis mine)