# Insert Binary Float using PQexecParams

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpq

May be I done a mistake, how can i please direct insert binary float in my table.
I don't know if i done the things right.
The code works but the values are not correct
Thank you for reply

```
static void to_nbo(double in, double *out) {
    uint64_t *i = (uint64_t *)&in;
    uint32_t *r = (uint32_t *)out;

    /* convert input to network byte order */
    r[0] = htonl((uint32_t)((*i) >> 32));
    r[1] = htonl((uint32_t)*i);
}
 const char command[] = "INSERT INTO car1 (id, price, sale)"
                         "VALUES($1::integer, $2::real, $3::real)";

  int nParams = 3;
  //const char *const paramValues[] = {"2.545","44.655"};

  const Oid paramTypes[] = {23, 700, 700};
  const int paramLengths[] = {sizeof(int), sizeof(int), sizeof(int)};
  const int paramFormats[] = {1, 1, 1};
  int resultFormat = 0;

  int test = htonl(45);
  double test2;
  double test3;
  to_nbo(75.585, &test2);
  to_nbo(8.4785, &test3);
  //char paramFloat[] ={0x41,0x40,0x00,0x00}; //12.0
  //char paramFloat1[] ={0x42,0x32,(char) 0x9e, (char) 0xb8}; //44.655
  //char paramFloat[] ={0x00,0x00, 0x40,0x41}; //12.0
  //char paramFloat1[] ={(char) 0xb8,(char) 0x9e,0x32,0x42}; //44.655
  //const char *const paramValues2[] = {paramFloat, paramFloat1};

 const char *const paramValues2[] = {(const char*)&test, (const char*)&test2, (const char*)&test3};

  /* PQexecParams INSERT */
  res = PQexecParams(conn, command, nParams, paramTypes, paramValues2, paramLengths, paramFormats, resultFormat);
  if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) {
      std::cout << "PQexecParams failed: " << PQresultErrorMessage(res)
                << std::endl;
  }
```

Comment: Note: it is good etiquette to link to your previous question, even if it has no accepted answer, or edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the PQExecParams function any information about the type of your binary data. It is trying to parse that binary junk as a string containing a floating point number.

Edit your SQL query like so:

```
const char command[] = "INSERT INTO car1 (id, price, sale)"
                         "VALUES($1::integer, $2::real, $3::real)";
```

this gives Postgres a hint what types you will be inserting.

Alternatively, fill in the `paramTypes[]` array; it has the following documentation:

> Specifies, by OID, the data types to be assigned to the parameter symbols. If paramTypes is NULL, or any particular element in the array is zero, the server infers a data type for the parameter symbol in the same way it would do for an untyped literal string.

Even then, you may need to do byteswapping as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42343759/1548468)

EDIT: looking through the public `postgres.h` header, I think you need to pass the output of `Float4GetDatum` to `PQExecParams`.

Comment: In my case which kind of values can I pass to ParamTypes[ ] please?

Comment: OIDs. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12531823/1548468)

Comment: I have modified the code, but the values in the table are still not correct. I don't know what is the mistake. Can you help please?

Comment: I cannot help unless you provide more information. How did you modify the code? What is "not correct"?

Comment: I edited the SQL query and  then i filled the paramType[ ] array.

Comment: I made a bytesswapping too, but the values in the Table are not the same with those in the query

Comment: Were you always passing `doubles` in? Because those are [`double`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) in PostgreSQL, while `real`  is for `float`s. If that still fails, edit your question with inputs *AND* outputs. Also note that `sizeof(int) != sizeof(double)`

Comment: So change the types in the query _and_ in `paramLengths`.

Comment: I have done exactly what you're described... It works now! Thanks